# SQLAlchemy: group_concat(case when...) possible?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, case, group-concat

I am trying to translate a MySQL query that uses `group_concat` in combination with `case when` to SQLAlchemy:

```
MySQL: group_concat(case when TableA.columnX=1 then TableA.id end)
```

I already tried queries like

```
func.group_concat(case([tableA.columnX], value=tableA.id)).label('tableA_id_concat'),
```

however this does not work (NotImplementedError). Is there a way to use `group_concat` in combination with `case when` in SQLAlchemy?

Note that `TableA.columnX` is a SQLAlchemy `Boolean()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the `case`. The correct call is:

```
func.group_concat(case(
                      [ 
                          (TableA.columnX, TableA.id) 
                      ]
                 )
).label('TableA_id_concat'),
```